# Stubbing a class with a block as a parameter in constructor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

If I have a class like

```
class MyClass

def initialize(&block)
  @myBlock = block
end

def process
  #...
  @myBlock.call
  #..
end
```

and I want to test a `DifferentClass` which needs to use `MyClass` and thus receive a block in the `new`.

How can I stub that block? What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

```
describe DifferentClass do
   it 'zomfg' do
    allow(MyClass).to receive(:new) do |&block|
      expect(block).to receive(:call)
      my_object = double
      allow(my_object).to receive(:process) { block.call }
      my_object
    end

    foo = MyClass.new {}
    # Here you should be passing the foo object to
    #  whatever method DifferentClass uses it in
    foo.process
  end
end
```